# Using RegExp for separate each five-character by '-' or something

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

Hello i have a TextField on my scene. It haves only digits, user input them by clicking on buttons (NumPad). I want to separate each five-character by '-' . User must input 20 digits

I'm using this code

```
var rexp:RegExp  = new RegExp("/^((\d{0,5})(\d{0,5})(\d{0,5})(\d{0,5}))$/"); 
trace(rexp.test(textEnter.text)); //always false
var s:String=textEnter.text.replace(rexp, "$2-$3-$4-$5"); 
trace(s);//format is fails
textEnter.text = s;
```

On [this site](http://www.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html) my patterns are working fine. But they aren't working in my AS3 script.

can you help me and say what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to instantiate a regex in AS3.  You can either use the constructor form or the regex literal form.

## Literal form

With this notation, the regex literal creates an implicit regex object, so you don't have to.  The following works fine:

```
var rexp:RegExp = /^((\d{0,5})(\d{0,5})(\d{0,5})(\d{0,5}))$/;
```

## Constructor form

If you really want to use the constructor form to instantiate your regex, then you *replace* the delimiting forward slashes with quotation marks.  You must also add a second backslash to any metasequences.

```
var rexp:RegExp  = new RegExp("^((\\d{0,5})(\\d{0,5})(\\d{0,5})(\\d{0,5}))$");
```

More info: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e92.html